# Suitable accommodation for alzheimers sufferer

Tags: accommodation

Where in the UK would be suitable for an elderly couple to stay when one has alzheimers?

The person who has alzheimers wants to go away for a few days but a few times through the day she has episodes where she wanders aimlessly and is not really with it during this time.

When she has these episodes through the day it is as simple as holding her hand or calling to her to make her come back.

At night she usually goes wandering around the house but cannot get out without a key so she is safe. At a hotel or caravan it is usually very easy to just walk out.

Answer (score 3):

Hotels, caravan parks, etc are not geared up for giving the kind of care that an Alzheimer sufferer needs. It's going to depend on whether the person going with them is able to provide the kind of care they need in that environment. I assume that's not the case. (You should probably also check with a healthcare professional as to whether a vacation is actually a good idea for the patient).

However many retirement and nursing homes are geared up to provide **respite care**, i.e. short stays by a patient who is normally cared for at home, but whose caregivers need a break for one reason or another. You might be able to find one who will take them as a couple, or the 'well' person might be able to stay nearby and visit or take the patient out (or, realistically, take a well-deserved break from the incredibly stressful job of caring full time for an Alzheimer patient). The cost will probably be higher than a hotel.

Comment: It does depend on the person but many Alzheimer sufferers do not do well when traveling and can have a big setback that has lasting results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it made me look up respite holidays for couples and came up with a company called Revitalise. @willeke she has been asking to go away for a while now, and they have only been able to do day trips. I will keep your advice in mind though.